# Reindexing embedded elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using a jhipster project with embedded elasticsearch container, I am writing a service to re-index all elasticsearchRepos, I am new to spring mvc..

Currently my approach is:

```
entityList = Jparepository.findAll()
elasticsearchRepository.deleteAll()
elasticsearchRepository.saveAll(entityList)
```

My question is do I need to use deleteAll?

Or does saveAll overwrites the previous overlapping data automatically?

Is there a better approach to reindex elasticsearchRepos?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of our data loading all into memory via `findAll` might not be a good idea. I would use pagination and save/update each page. There is small module which is doing it in smaller batches. Not sure if it is already updated for jhipster 7 but you can have look at the code

https://github.com/geraldhumphries/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer/blob/master/generators/app/templates/src/main/java/package/service/_ElasticsearchIndexService.java#L172

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is deleteAll operation required in this?

Comment: As the entities are indexed with a stable ID you don't need to delete everything from the elasticsearch index before. You may delete the index before but it should not be required: https://github.com/geraldhumphries/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer/blob/820e99899c5fb4a097251c07ed7ebdb70f18dea8/generators/app/templates/src/main/java/package/service/_ElasticsearchIndexService.java#L174